# Customer Community users can't access the new enhanced Notes related list?

Tags: customer-community, notes

I can't find any documentation on this topic..

We enabled the new 'enhanced' note taking tool for our internal org, and I would like our Customer Community users to be able to use them as well.

**However, when logged in as a CC user, the entire related list for Notes is missing from their page layouts - all they can see is the old Notes and Attachments list.**

When our *internal* users switch to the Customer Community (not by logging in using a CC license, but by accessing the Community from their internal license), they can see the enhanced notes related lists just fine.

Also, messing with the read/write access CC users have to parent objects of the new notes doesn't seem to affect their visibility to CC users. Nor does changing the sharing settings of the individual note.

Is this an unacknowledged limitation of this new feature or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is for Accounts and contacts only.

You will have to contact salesforce to enable it

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring16_release_notes.pdf

pg 292

> Customer Community Licenses Can Access Notes and Attachments on
> Accounts and Contacts Users with a Customer Community license can now
> access Notes and Attachments on accounts and contacts using the
> note-taking tool.
>
> Previously, this access was blocked. Don’t worry
> about your users with a Customer Community license seeing data they’re
> not supposed to—you can specify whether Notes and Attachments are
> public or private.
>
> Note: To turn on this access, contact Salesforce.
>
> Orgs created after the Spring '16 release get this access by default.
>
> When access is enabled, users can access Notes and Attachments in
> communities and in the API, but not in the UI for portals. Access to
> the new Notes feature isn’t included. SEE ALSO: Salesforce Help:
> What’s the Difference Between Notes and the Old Note-Taking Tool?

Notes is not available for Partner and Customer Portal Licenses

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/notes_admin_setup.htm

Comment: Hey thanks for finding this, looks like the enhanced note tool is just not available in the Community/Portal, and they are just starting to partially roll out traditional notes... what a half baked feature release!